# Who is the manufacturer of the Y31 5133 mic?

Tags: power-electronics, semiconductors, microphone, mems, mems-microphone

My question is in this PCBA I need the information of the who is the manufacturers of the mic the full details of that mic...[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: MEMS microphones are difficult to identify because their markings are obscure compared to other types of IC devices. If you're trying to replace this microphone, I would suggest taking the part off the board and try to find another microphone with the same footprint.

Comment: I need the full details details about mems mic models in tws